# Any place to find canonical data structures and algorithms implemented in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm going through Skiena's The Algorithm Design Manual which uses C. All the examples (binary tree search, etc.) are pretty simple, but I'd like to see them in C# to make sure I'm working through them correctly.

Are there any sites that provide all the basic algorithms and data structures in C#? Right now I've just been googling for the particular thing I'm looking for, I'd be surprised if there wasn't a more definitive site out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[NGenerics](http://code.google.com/p/ngenerics/)** seems to be a good library for data structures and algorithms.  I've used a few of their tree implementations with good results.

Answer (score 1):

There are books like [Data Structures and Algorithms Using C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521670152) and [Numerical Methods, Algorithms and Tools in C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0849374790), but I doubt that you will find a good tutorial out there that is specifically for C#.

But on the other hand, why are you learning algorithms for any specific language? Essentially, they are language agnostic, and should be treated as pure math. Does it really mater if you define your array as

```
int* array = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
```

or

```
int[] array = new int[10];
```

?